# Array.equal() giving wrong output

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, equals

To my understanding, the following code should print `true`, since both elements are `equal`.

**From java docs Array.get() will return:**

> Returns the value of the indexed component in the specified array
>   object. The value is automatically wrapped in an object if it has a
>   primitive type.

However, when I run the following code it is printing
 `false`:

```
  public class Test1 {

    static boolean equalTest(Object array1, Object array2) {
        return Array.get(array1, 0).equals(Array.get(array2, 0));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[1];
        byte[] b = new byte[1];
        a[0] = 3;
        b[0] = 3;
        System.out.println(equalTest(a, b));
    }
}
```

My question is isn't classes implementing Number are or should be directly comparable to one another.

Comment: They are not the same type? `int != byte`

Comment: Data types are mismatching

Comment: imho it should print false, since they're not the same type.

Comment: `Array.get` returns an `Object`: `Integer.valueOf(3).equals(Byte.valueOf((byte) 3))` is false too.

Comment: No I am equating values. please check return type of get

Comment: Yes, is not an integer 32 bits long? And a byte, what 8?

Comment: @Animal it's [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get(java.lang.Object,%20int)).

Comment: @JoshuaTree int is 32 bit and byte is 8 bit...that's what's causing the error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with arrays really. Your comparison is equivalent to:

```
Object x = Integer.valueOf(3);
Object y = Byte.valueOf((byte) 3);
boolean equal = x.equals(y);
```

That's never going to return `true`.

Even though your original arrays are of the primitive types, `Array.get` returns `Object`, so you're getting the boxed types - and comparing values of those different types.

Comment: I"m curious, does y have a legible value?

Comment: @JoshuaTree: What do you mean by "legible"? It's entirely valid - it's the byte 3 (in `Byte` form).

Comment: @JonSkeet---SIR thanks a lot .... :)Your answers right bang on target...:)

Comment: @JonSkeet I did'nt quite get why it dosen't return true...as in if it returns object?

Comment: @AndyTurner As in not simpler or the equality check was reversed? If it's the latter, equality should be commutative so it doesn't matter

Comment: @Michael reversed. `equals` should be *symmetrical*, but there's no guarantee that it is in general (of course, it is in this case).

Comment: @Akshay: It's comparing objects of two different execution-time types (`Byte` and `Integer`). That *should* return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get(java.lang.Object,%20int)) of `Array.get(Object array,int index)` method, the value returned is automatically wrapped in an object if it has a primitive type. So, if you add the following lines:

```
System.out.println(Array.get(array1, 0).getClass());
System.out.println(Array.get(array2, 0).getClass());
```

you will see the output is

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Byte
```

The `equals` method of `Integer` class first of all checks if the object it is being compared to is also an instance of `Integer`, if not , then no further checks are required, they are not equal.
That's the reason you see the output is false as the objects being compared for equality are `Integer` and `Byte`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Array.get` invocations return `Integer` and `Byte` object instances. These are not equal according to `Integer.equals` because the class type differs.

Answer (score 0):

The array data types don't match. One is `int` and the other is `byte`. Since they're being passed to the function as Objects, they'll end up being `Integer` and `Byte`. So in order to compare them properly, you need to type-cast them to the same type. Something like:

```
static boolean equalTest(Object array1, Object array2) {
  int int1 = (int) Array.get(array1, 0);
  int int2 = (int) Array.get(array2, 0);
  return int1.equals(int2);
  // OR return int1 == int2;
}
```

Comment: Well, they're not `int` and `byte`, because `Array.get` returns `Object` - they'll be the wrapper types. (But yes, it's because the types aren't the same.)

Comment: Jon Skeet and I agree. Then we must both be right. :D @jonskeet

Comment: True, but auto-boxing should take care of it.

Comment: That's my point though - the types *being compared* are `Integer` and `Byte`, not `int` and `byte`. Casting directly to `int` will give a `ClassCastException`, too - you'd need to cast to `byte` and then convert that `byte` to `int` (whether implicitly or explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Array.get()` method returns an object, so for `int` it'll return `Integer`, and for `byte`, it will return `Byte`. So `.equals()` method will return false because it first sees whether the type is the same, and then compares the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the JavaDoc for [`Array.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get(java.lang.Object,%20int)) you'll see:

> The value is automatically wrapped in an object if it has a primitive
>   type.

So your `byte`s become `Byte`s and your `int`s become `Integer`s.

That means the function you're calling is [`Integer.equals(Object)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

This is implemented like so:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

You're not passing it an `Integer`, you're passing it a `Byte` so that's why it returns false.